# How to handle multiple VueJS SPAs application in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API application, I want to serve two VueJS apps, one for **Admin** and one for **Users**.

So I did the setup configuration like this:

```
app.Map("/users",
    adminApp =>
    {
        adminApp.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "AppFront";
            spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "AppFront"))
            };
            spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
            spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", port: 4200);
        });
    }
);

app.Map("/admin",
    adminApp =>
    {
        adminApp.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "AppAdmin";
            spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "AppAdmin"))
            };
            spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4201");
            spa.UseVueCli(npmScript: "serve", port: 4201);
        });
    }
);
```

Here is the project structure:

[image]

The problem is, when I tried to access the admin page, for example:
It is not loading the script correctly.

[image]

I found that the problem is because I'm not adding the prefix "**admin**" to VueJS **Javascript path**.

[image]

How can I add this prefix? Is it possible?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

because your vue base url not "/", you need to set [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl) in vue.config.js on every vuejs project root

```js
// ./AppAdmin/vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/admin'
}

// ./AppFront/vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/users'
}
```